# Dont get field in result create method django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a method of creating clien. one of the body fields of my method is client_users which is not in my client model. He has a foreign key for clients. I overwrite the create method and it is ok. But when I return the method I have this error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `clientes_usuarios` on serializer `ClienteCreateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Cliente` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Cliente' object has no attribute 'clientes_usuarios'.
```

My field in my serializer:

```
class ClienteCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    endereco_residencial = EnderecoSerializer(read_only=False)
    endereco_cobranca = EnderecoSerializer(read_only=False,required=False)
    contatos = ContatoClienteSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, required=False)
    certificados = CertificadoSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='usuario.email')
    cnpj = serializers.CharField(max_length=14, min_length=14, source='usuario.cpf_cnpj')
    foto = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    data_abertura = serializers.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, required=False, allow_null=True)
    clientes_usuarios = UsuarioClienteCreateSerializer(many=True,read_only=False)
```

I have outher methods like this and they works fine

Comment: add your complete serializer class and all related models

Comment: If this is during `create` you may have an issue using that serializer because UsuarioClienteCreateSerializer is a serializer to another model as opposed to a foreign key. If i'm right about that i have solved this by having a write serializer with a primary key reference, and a read with nested serializer. Example:
https://medium.com/@unpluggedcoder/use-corresponding-serializer-class-for-different-request-method-in-django-rest-framework-ce0efc04045d

Comment: Mudar para português
The creation process works fine. I just want to not show the cliente_usuarios in the method result. after this method, the error is generated. because drf does not find in the key or attr on the cliente object

Comment: my model cliente had ForiengKey to usuarios_clientes but related_name was usuarios. I changed to usuarios_clientes same field name of Serializer and work